# Read file permissions in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, permissions, posix, nsfilemanager

I am trying to read file permissions in Cocoa of a file having rw-r--r-- (hence 0644).
The code I am using is the following:

```
NSUInteger permissions;
permissions=[[fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:file error:nil] filePosixPermissions];
NSLog(@"Permissions:%lu",permissions);
```

And the result is 420 when the expected result should be 644.

Do I do a calculation error ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see 0644, it's actually the octal (base 8) representation of the permissions.

420 is the base 10 equivalent of 0644 in octal.

NSLog can output octal with:

```
NSLog(@"Permissions:%o", permissions);
```

Comment: That's so obvious now you tell... Thanks !